Obtaining the stabilizer outcome by small operators
Suppose we want to obtain the measurement outcome of the stabilizer $X_1X_2X_3X_4X_5X_6$. Of course, by measuring $X_1X_2$, $X_3X_4$, $X_5X_6$ in this order and combining these three outcomes, we can obtain the measurement outcome of the stabilizer.
What I would like to know is that, in some document, it is said that
i) if we measure $X_1X_2$, $Z_2Z_3$, $X_3X_4$, $X_5X_6$ in this order, we cannot obtain the outcome of the stabilizer.
ii)if we measure $X_1X_2$, $X_3X_4$, $Z_2Z_3$, $X_5X_6$ in this order, we can obtain the outcome of the stabilizer.
iii)if we measure $X_5X_6$, $Z_6Z_7$, $X_1X_2$, $X_3X_4$ in this order, we can obtain the outcome of the stabilizer.
Could you explain why these statements hold? I guess the commutation relationships play an important role, but I am not sure how to verify the statements are true.

This can actually get complicated to solve, because of lattice surgery. For example, measuring these Pauli strings will measure $X_1X_2X_3X_4X_5X_6$ and no other operators over qubits 1-6:

$Z_{98}$
$X_1X_{98}$
$Z_{98}Z_{99}$
$X_3X_{98}$
$Z_{98}$
$X_5X_{98}$
$Z_{98}Z_{99}$
$X_2X_{98}$
$Z_{98}$
$X_4X_{98}$
$Z_{98}Z_{99}$
$X_6X_{98}$
$Z_{98}$

If you don't know the ZX calculus, this sounds totally wild. If you do know the ZX calculus, it's quite easy to see it works because the corresponding graph reduces to the same thing as the graph corresponding to measuring $X_1X_2X_3X_4X_5X_6$ when you repeatedly apply leaf-cutting and spider-fusion. They're both ultimately just a central Z-type connected component linked to X-type components touching each of the qubits:

The way I would approach this problem in general is as follows:

Given a series of Pauli product measurements, you can produce a stabilizer ZX calculus graph that postselects these measurements one after the other.
Given a stabilizer ZX calculus graph, you can compute the stabilizer generators of its exterior edges.
If $+P$ or $-P$ on the input edges is in the stabilizer group of those generators, then a circuit measuring the specified operators must have a stabilizer flow $P \rightarrow \pm\Pi_{m \in M} (-1)^m$ for some set of measurements $M$ somewhere. If $P$ isn't a stabilizer of that state, then the original circuit cannot be measuring $P$.

(At some point I'll probably add a stim.Circuit.flow_generators method, at which point you could just feed in a circuit with a bunch of MPP instructions and get back flow generators and see if the measurement you want can be built out of those generators. This would equivalently solve your problem.)

Thank you. I am looking forward to stim.Circuit.flow_generators method!

@david It exists in stim~=1.14.dev now: https://github.com/quantumlib/Stim/commit/0685b5a2e784c24b8898ceb1a01e01db34ab47fd

Much as I'm a ZX-calculus fan, as in Craig's answer, I guess the most "standard" way to see this is using the stabilizer formalism, e.g. as in Nielsen-Chuang. I'll add a very quick reminder of what this is at the bottom of my answer.
My interpretation of your question is that you've got a system of qubits and all you know about them is that they're stabilized by $m X_1 \ldots X_6$, for some $m \in \{-1, +1\}$. In other words, they're described by a stabilizer group $S = \langle m X_1 \ldots X_6 \rangle$. You want to perform a series of measurements such that you can infer $m$ from the outcomes.
I'll just go over the measurement sequence (iii) because it's perhaps the most interesting one, as evidenced by David Dentelski and DaftWullie's differing answers.
(iii)

Measuring $X_5 X_6$ puts us in Case 3 of the formalism (see below); we get some non-deterministic measurement outcome $m_{56}$ and we add $m_{56} X_5 X_6$ as a generator of the stabilizer group, so that $S' = \langle m_{56} X_5 X_6, m X_1 \ldots X_6 \rangle$.

Measuring $Z_6 Z_7$ puts us in Case 2 of the formalism, because this anti-commutes with both $m_{56} X_5 X_6$ and $m X_1 \ldots X_6$. The measurement outcome $m_{67}$ is thus random. We must first rewrite $S'$ so that $Z_6 Z_7$ only anti-commutes with one generator; we can do this by multiplying $m X_1 \ldots X_6$ by $m_{56} X_5 X_6$ to get $S' = \langle m_{56} X_5 X_6, m_{56} m X_1 \ldots X_4 \rangle$. Now the formalism tells us the new group $S''$ is formed by replacing generator $m_{56} X_5 X_6$ by $m_{67} Z_6 Z_7$ to get $S'' = \langle m_{67} Z_6 Z_7, m_{56} m X_1 \ldots X_4 \rangle$.

Measuring $X_1 X_2$ puts us in Case 3 of the formalism; we get some non-deterministic measurement outcome $m_{12}$ and we add $m_{12} X_1 X_2$ as a generator of the stabilizer group, so that $S''' = \langle m_{12} X_1 X_2, m_{67} Z_6 Z_7, m_{56} m X_1 \ldots X_4 \rangle$.

Finally, measuring $X_3 X_4$ puts us in Case 1 of the formalism, because $S'''$ contains the product of the two generators $m_{12} X_1 X_2$ and $m_{56} m X_1 \ldots X_4$ which is $m_{12} m_{56} m X_3 X_4$. So the measurement result $m_{34}$ is deterministically equal to $m_{12} m_{56} m$! That is, $m = m_{34} m_{12} m_{56}$.


You can use the same idea to show that sequence (i) doesn't let you find $m$, but (iii) does.

Stabilizer formalism reminder: this says that if I have a stabilizer group $S = \langle s_1 \ldots s_r \rangle$ that describes my system of qubits (the qubits' state is in the $+1$ eigenspace of all elements of $S$), and I measure some Hermitian Pauli $p$, the new stabilizer group $S'$ that describes the state of my qubits is as follows:
Case 1 - if $p \in S$ or $-p \in S$, then the measurement outcome is deterministically $+1$ or $-1$ respectively, and the new group $S'$ is exactly the old one $S$.
Case 2 - if $p \notin N(S)$ (i.e. it anti-commutes with something in $S$), then WLOG we can assume $p$ anti-commutes with $s_1$ only (by multiplying other elements by $s_1$ as needed). Then the measurement outcome $m$ is completely random, and the new group $S'$ is $\langle mp, s_2, \ldots, s_r \rangle$, i.e. $s_1$ is replaced by $mp$.
Case 3 - if $p \in N(S) - (S \cup -S)$ (i.e. it commutes with everything in $S$ but neither $p$ nor $-p$ is in $S$), then the measurement outcome $m$ depends on the actual state of our qubits (it's neither deterministic nor completely random, necessarily), and the new group $S'$ is $\langle mp, s_1, s_2, \ldots, s_r \rangle$, i.e. $mp$ is added as a generator.

As a sufficient condition for when you can get the observable you want, you can use commutation. Take both cases (ii) and (iii). The $ZZ$ term commutes with all the terms to its right by virtue of acting on different qubits. This means that you can reorder the measurements so that you can perform the three $XX$ measurements first (at which point you can evaluate your stabilizer) and only then perform the $ZZ$ measurement.
Case (i) obviously cannot be reordered like that, so is not so straightforward (given Craig Gidney's point). However, the fact that they do not commute, and cannot be grouped together should at least make you suspicious. At that point, to be rigorous, it's worth showing an example of s atstae that you measure where you get the wrong expectation value for the stabilizer. Let's take, for example, the state
$$
|\psi\rangle=|++++++\rangle.
$$
Obviously, when I measure $X_1X_2$, I get the outcome $+1$, and I should get the outcome $+1$ for the overall stabilizer. However, next I measure $Z_2Z_3$. The two different outcomes occur with 50:50 probability. Maybe it's easiest to take one outcome and follow through the consequences. So, imagine we get the $\pm1$ answer, meaning the state is now
$$
|+\rangle(|++\rangle\pm|--\rangle)|+++\rangle.
$$
When we measure $X_5X_6$ we're still going to get a $+1$ outcome. However, the expectation of $X_3X_4$ is 0. Hence, we'd conclude that $\langle X_1X_2X_3X_4X_5X_6\rangle=0$, which we know to be wrong.

As long as don't measure operators which anti commute, you are fine. Once you did, the value of the previous operators is random (it is like measuring a single qubit in X and then in Z).
So, in i), the second operator anti commutes with the first. In ii), the third anti commutes with the first two, but it commutes with thier multiplication, so each of them is random but $X_1X_2X_3X_4$ does not change.
But iii) seems wrong. Maybe it should be $Z_5Z_6$?

The lattice surgery cnot builds a cnot out of a series of anti-commuting measurements, so commutation is not a necessary condition.
